# Bars appear when I animate an element with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

When I animate an element with Jquery some piece of it rest at the older position.
It's difficult to explain so I have uploaded an image.
Do you think it's a problem of the browsers, Jquery or eventually of me ?

[Image of what I try to explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElEVm.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Could you include your code, and which browsers you get the error in?

Comment: This is the link of the page.
I use Google Chrome 25.0.1364.97 m
[link](http://www.home-smarter.com/Gerer.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at it, It seems to work fine if you remove the margin-left on your ul.MenuMaisons. It works fine in Internet explorer. This must be a browser issue with Chrome.

```
ul.MenuMaisons {
   width: 250px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 100px;
   left: 50%;
   /*margin-left: -427.5px;*/
}
```

Sadly I am unaware of what removing the margin-left will do to your website. You could try with padding instead.

Comment: Thanks it works fine when I remove the margin-left.
I will use an other way for the position of the element.